# python unit tests import module error

Tags: python, unit-testing, import, module, runtime-error

When I run units tests , these module import err are raised.

```
test_sort (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure) ... ERROR
test_deep_ops (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure) ... ERROR

   **from pyparsing import \
ImportError: cannot import name infixNotation**
```

More errors are captured [here](http://elasticsearchpy.blogspot.com/2017/03/running-tests-python-27.html).

github repo: https://github.com/maggienj/ActiveData

Comment: @karthikr please check.

Comment: Format code block to make it readable.

Comment: the code blocks are already formatted.